# How does the function only work one time after an event happened? And how to remove the function after another event happened

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

When I shrink the window width to 576 my function works, I am using code for preventing multiple times of resizing.

My main problem is that when I shrink it more times under 576, my function 'slideTotal' works as many as times I shrink.

Also if I shrink it to a number above 576, my function still works, does not stop.

How can the function work just one time only until I shrink to above 576, and how can I stop the function after more than 576 width again?

I tried a boolean but the function doesn't stop, it doesn't work with a boolean.

```
var footerMenu = ['#about', '#help']

function slideDown(){
  footerMenu.forEach(function(list){
      $(list+' p').click(function(){
        $(list+' ul').slideToggle(300)
      })
    })
}

function slideClear(){
  for( let i = 0; i < footerMenu.length; i++){ 
    $(footerMenu[i]+' p').click(function(){
      var choice = footerMenu[i]
      footerMenu.splice(i, 1);
      footerMenu.forEach(function(list){ 
          $(list+' ul').slideUp(300)
      })
      footerMenu.splice(i, 0, choice);
    })
  }
}

function slideTotal(){

  slideDown()
  slideClear()

}

function resizeDone( ) {

  $vWidth = $(window).width();

  if($vWidth <576){
    console.log("Width: Less than 576");
    slideTotal()
    }else{
      console.log("Width: More than 576");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  var delta = 300;
  var timer = null;

  $(window).resize(function(){

    clearTimeout( timer );
    timer = setTimeout( resizeDone, delta );

  });
});
```

I need some code for the function to trigger just once and stop after another event has happened.

Comment: make a bool type flag, and besides the screen resolution check it

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц I tried boolean like that, but function still work after shrinking more than width 576, I think I need code stop the function

Answer (score 0):

```
let flag = false;

if($vWidth <576){
    console.log("Width: Less than 576");
        if (!flag){
            slideTotal();
            flag = true;
        }
    }else{
      flag = false;
      console.log("Width: More than 576");
    }
```